# How to parse a dynamic Json to a string?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following valid `Json` checked on www.jsonlint.com. Below is part of `Json` the complete `Json` is too big to post here.

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "Micheal Jackson",
        "pic_large": "https://scontent.x.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14909900_10154513795037597_3241587822245799922_n.jpg?oh=54ead7e0ba74b45b632d96da1515ccf8&oe=591C4938",
        "id": "10154729171332597"
    }]
}
```

When I want to deserialize it using `JsonConvert` I get following error calling the code below:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Facebook.JsonArray' to 'string'".

```
string json = myFeed.data;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Is there any way to deserialize `Json` dynamic objects to strings?

Comment: add your `Result` class here as well.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @L.B the classes are properly mapped the only problem is that the `Json` is retrieved in dynamic type.

Comment: I don't see any dynamic types in your example.  Can you create an [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it, is by creating a class named data, with instance variables name, pic_large an id and then apply the following method of using JsonConvert.SerializeObject and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}
                                            //check the generics on class Product
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>  (output);
```

for more info check 
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm